# Is .bank owned by banking industry or not?

Tags: dns, financial

According to https://idc-insights-community.com/financial/financial-services-technology/the-four-letter-word-that-could-change-the-busines

Banking Industry was lobbying for .bank

But as I read this
http://www.uniteddomains.com/new-top-level-domain/bank-domain-registration/

> Domain Security Company is a Wisconsin-based LLC that will establish
>   .SECURE and .BANK. The company's goal is to make the Internet a safer
>   and more secure place by employing a mix of technology and processes
>   including industry standards for high security websites.
>
> http://www.uniteddomains.com/service/aboutus/
>
> For every sale you send our way, you earn a 10% commission,
>   automatically deposited into your affiliate account. Just like our
>   site, it's simple and easy.

I have some serious doubt that it is finally owned by banking industry but by another commercial affliate network.

Comment: I don't see the security implications of this. It sounds more like a complaint that a company might monopolise the sale of `.bank` domain names.

Comment: if .bank is really owned by banks I would trust them as for their interest to really secure .bank if it is owned by some marketing company then security will be just ... marketing promise :)

Comment: They're just domain names. The banks would be the same as they are today.

Answer (score 3):

This is marketing hype. The `.bank` domains are just like any others that require you to be a particular type of organisation (e.g. `.edu` or `.museum`) in order to buy one. There is no guarantee of security, any more than you have with your bank at the moment.

Comment: I believe it may be *possible* for a tld administrative community to (try to) enforce certain restrictions and compliance. One thing I would love to see is banks (and other financial institutions) being required to use bcrypt/scrypt/PBKDF2/etc to hash passwords (uniquely-salted) before storing as well as a few other basic web-security measures (like allowing special characters in passwords, I'm looking at you, CitiBank).

Comment: That would be nice. But I have a feeling that `.com` is so engrained in people's minds that banks will just stick with that and continue to ignore security recommendations.